# Powershell - return custom object to C# host

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I have the following powershell script which loads a custom .NET DLL this contains the ScriptResult class, it is intern executed from a VB.NET app.

```
Add-Type -Path $myLibPath

$result = New-Object TheLibrary.ScriptResult
```

In the VB.NET app I want to get the result object but the following doesnt seem to work

```
'get the script result
Dim result As ScriptResult = run.SessionStateProxy.GetVariable("result")
```

What am I not doing correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) define the variable to the runtime first with

`run.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("result", null)`

b) maybe could help to mark $result as global *(not verified)*:

`$global:result = New-Object TheLibrary.ScriptResult`

Comment: After a painful search I was able to success with your second option. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`GetVariable` returns a `PSVariable` instance. The variable's value is in the `.Value` property. You'll probably need to cast it (`DirectCast`) to your `ScriptResult` type as `Value` returns an `Object`.